# Generic extensions method for IQueryable<out T>

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, telerik-mvc

Honestly I hate extension methods as [disscussed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4927702/should-i-prefer-static-methods-in-c/4927783#4927783) before.

I have a extension method as "ApplySorting"

```
public static IQueryable<Brand> ApplySorting(this IQueryable<Brand> data,
               IList<GroupDescriptor> groupDescriptors, 
               IList<SortDescriptor> sortDescriptors)
```

It has been implemented for `IQueryable<Brand>` it is look like nice. I need another method for Category, I should implement another method as `IQueryable<Category>` and this story goes.

Question; How can I define `IQueryable<T>` to stop repeated extension method?
It should be look like this (of course it is not valid code VS 2010 stoped me.)

```
public static IQueryable<T> ApplySorting(this IQueryable<T> data,
                            IList<GroupDescriptor> groupDescriptors,
                            IList<SortDescriptor> sortDescriptors) 
                where T : IEntity
```

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static IQueryable<T> ApplySorting<T>(this IQueryable<T> data,
                            IList<GroupDescriptor> groupDescriptors,
                            IList<SortDescriptor> sortDescriptors) 
                where T : IEntity
```

(I added a type variable to the method)

Answer (score 4):

You need to make the method **generic** in order to have generic parameters.

In other words, this will work:

```
public static IQueryable<T> ApplySorting<T>(this IQueryable<T> data,
                            IList<GroupDescriptor> groupDescriptors,
                            IList<SortDescriptor> sortDescriptors) 
                            where T : IEntity
```

(Note that `<T>` is present in method's name)

All LINQ extension methods are defined this way, but in most cases passing the concrete type is optional due to type inference, that's why it's easy to miss it.

Comment: great thanks! but I am really sorry that your and Rik answer same but I accepted rik answer because it listed first answer.